# Why test organizations furnished through the Environment Hub becomes suddenly considered as production?

Tags: beta-managed-package, environment-hub

I received an unexpected error

```
Installation errors: 
1) Package(0331n000000null) Unable to install beta package, Details: The package you attempted to install is a beta package, which you can only install in sandbox or Developer Edition organizations.
```

when installing a new 2GMP into test organization, furnished through the Environment Hub.

I din't receive this error two days ago when I was able to successfully install the previous beta package version into this environment.

I am able to create and delete Apex Classes on this environment, so this is not a real production org.

Comment: When you say you previously installed a beta on the same environment, have you uninstalled that earlier beta before attempting to install the new one? You probably have, just checking.

Comment: Yes, I did. Twice installed, twice uninstalled. Now I can't install neither new version nor the version which I have just uninstalled.

Comment: Sounds like a scenario where you need to raise a Support Case with Salesforce :(

Comment: I no longer work for a client with Premier support, so I think I can't. Unless if this is covered with free partner support

Comment: All you can do is try. We don't have Premier but we do get some technical support.